# How to handle such large test cases in Stick Length Problems on CSES?

Tags: sorting, binary-search

I'm fixing the equal length as k, and finding cost by binary Search method, not binary something like trinary and changes low or high state according to my mid1 and mid2 (mid2 = mid1 + 1).

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()  {
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  vector<long long> p(n);
  for(auto& y : p)  {
    cin >> y;
  }
  long long maxVal = *max_element(p.begin(), p.end());
  long long low = 0, high = maxVal * n;
  long long minCost = maxVal * n;
  while(low <= high)  {
    long long mid1 = low + (high - low) / 2;
    long long mid2 = mid1 + 1;
    long long cost1 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)  {
      cost1 += llabs(mid1 - p[i]);
    }
    long long cost2 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)  {
      cost2 += llabs(mid2 - p[i]);
    }
    minCost = min({minCost, cost1, cost2});
    if(cost1 <= cost2)  {
      high = mid1 - 1;
    } else  {
      low = mid1 + 1;
    }
  }
  cout << minCost;
}
```

What could be the reason for my solution which is failing test cases 6?

I want to handle large test cases.

Comment: What is "test cases 6"?